# Will dd if=/image.iso of=/dev/sdb copy the image onto pendrive or burn it?

Tags: system-installation, iso, dd, unetbootin

Or maybe I should just use unetbootin instead (*crying*)

Comment: Try unetbootin method.It's simple and an easy one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dd` to "burn" (actually its extracting the files to the USB)  your iso's to an USB drive and make the pendrive bootable. But this only works if your distro supports it.

If your installing Ubuntu, then your good to go.